# TASM: switch from model small to model large

Tags: assembly, model, x86-16, tasm

I am using assembly 8086 with tasm, at model small.
I want to switch to large model because I need a bigger place for the code and data.

Can someone please explain me the differences between model small and large, and how do I change my program from model small to model large?

Comment: tried documentation?

Comment: What research have you done before asking this question?  All the things you ask are well explained in many places in the internet.

Comment: I remember when I asked my professor "What happens if I run out of space in the program segment?". And he answered "You will never write assembly programs that large.".